# Access 2010 ADP appending a 1 to the end of object names

Tags: ms-access-2010, adp

I've managed to break Access on my laptop.  I had Office 2010 installed, then decided to upgrade to Office 2013 after going to an MS presentation.  This wasn't the best move for me.

I realised after installation that Access 2013 doesn't support ADP's.  So ran the installer and removed Access and reinstalled it from Office 2010.  At this point all is well.

This morning I decided to uninstall Office 2013 entirely and reinstall Office 2010. Most of the office apps are working fine, but when I try and run my ADP in Access 2010, it seems to be appending a 1 to the end of all of my database objects, then errors out saying it cannot find the object.

I'm getting the following error trying to type into a combo box on the opening form of the database.  " cannot find the object 'Company1'".

The correct name for the table object it cannot find is Company, not Company1.  It seems to be adding the one on for other objects as well.

I have checked the connection property for the database and it is testing okay.  I can open up the table in design view, and it shows me all of the columns etc, but I cannot open it in datasheet view to see the rows.  I get the same error as above.

I don't believe that the ADP file itself is corrupt, because I can open it fine from another PC.

I have tried uninstalling Office 2010 and reinstalling from scratch, but I can't seem to solve the issue.

Is there a registry setting or something that is playing with the object names?

I'm at my wits end, so any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
Mike.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found your question when having a similar problem with my PC; in my case, I added Access 2010 to a PC with Access 2003 - when I did that, it caused problems when I tried to filter on forms. The solution was to downgrade a DLL

C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\MSClientDataMgr\MSCDM.DLL

Version 14.0.4731.1000 had to be downgraded to 11.0.8204.0. Suddenly filtering worked again!

So last night I was testing one of my ADPs in Access 2010 (they want us to upgrade!) and I got the same problem you had - it was appending "1" to tables, views, stored procedures, etc. So on a whim, I changed back to the newer DLL. It did the trick and I have my tables/objects back! It appears that different versions of the DLL have problems with different versions of MS Access.

Although you may have uninstalled Access 2013, it wouldn't have changed all your DLLs to the old one. I'd suggest that you rename the MSCDM.DLL (right-click it and get the version number first) and see if you can get Version 14 installed in its place. It shouldn't require a registration or a reboot - mine worked when I replaced the DLL and opened my ADP again.

Good luck!

- Kevin

Comment: Having same issue on Windows 10, MSCDM.DLL has version 14.0.4731.1000 on failing machine, and same version on working machine. So it is not the case.